# timestamp in Magento2?

Tags: php, database, magento2.2

**Difference between**

```
->addColumn('created_at', Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, ['nullable' => false, **'default' => Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT]**,'Created At')
```

**VS**

```
 ->addColumn('created_at', Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP, null, [], 'Created At')
```

If anyone knows please explain me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default means a pre-filled value - so if you want to have created_at populated automatically by the database with the current time when a new record is created you'd use the top example.

For an updated_at field you wouldn't have this set - you'd update explicitly in code when the record is being modified and it will be null until the record is explicitly set.